# Is it acceptable to use "google" as a verb?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, writing

With the popularity and ubiquity of Google, it has become a verb to describe "searching for something online" and it appears in conversations and informal writing.

How can I know if it is acceptable to use "google" in more formal writing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is now an official verb (since 2006), added to the [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google) dictionary and the OED.
So I would say: yes.

- [Do you google?](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2006/10/do-you-google.html) (google blog)
- [To Google or Not to Google](http://web.archive.org/web/20060707062623/http://msnbc.msn.com/id/13720643/): "According to the OED, you can now Google away to your heart's content."

Comment: Should "Google" be capitalised or not? My spellchecker thinks it should, but I disagree...

Comment: @Seamus, Verbs derived from proper nouns are not usually capitalised. Feel free to google and to hoover. (And my spellchecker is happy with both of those.)

Answer (score 10):

I generally recommend the following for using newly minted words:

- In casual or social conversation and in non-formal writing, go for it.
- In formal or professional conversation/presentation and in most professional writing, substitute a comparable but more-neutral term. "I Googled 'potato' but found too many entries" and "I **searched** 'potato' but found too many entries" are practically identical in meaning.

Sometimes using "Googled" is appropriate for your voice in business writing. This will usually be in less-formal media like project-team blogs or webcasts (where the reader expects colloquial usage).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's acceptable. This leads to some fun sentences, like "A few years back, I googled something on altavista and found ..."

Comment: http://www.thechurchofgoogle.org/ Commandment 3: Thou shalt not use Google as a verb to mean the use of any lesser Search Engine.