# Term for when noun becomes a verb

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for when a well-known noun such as Google, Yelp, Snapchat, etc. become a verb. People now say, let's google it and it is understood that they will use google to search something. Or let's yelp it to check nearby restaurants or information pertaining to nearby restaurants. It usually only happens to popular companies, as no one says let's yahoo this. Is there a term that describes this phenomenon?

Comment: It's called ***verbing***

Comment: It seems that while verbing is what I am looking for, it is not officially recognized by merriam-webster. :(

Comment: [Verbification](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbification) from verb + Latin *making*.

Comment: You may also like this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/78799/17956

Comment: Related: 1. [“To science the sh*t out of something”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305782/to-science-the-sht-out-of-something) 2. [Which nouns can be used as verbs?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/which-nouns-can-be-used-as-verbs) 3. (posted 5 years ago)  [Is it acceptable to use “google” as a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/is-it-acceptable-to-use-google-as-a-verb) 4. [Company Name as Verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197662/company-name-as-verb)