# What do you call a brand name that is used as a verb

Tags: verbs, nouns, brands

What do you call a word used as a verb like:

To hoover instead of to vacuum.
A kleenex instead of a facial tissue or paper handkerchief.
etc.

Brand verbification? Is there a single word to describe it?

tia,
Plumafina

Comment: related: **1** [Company Name as Verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197662/company-name-as-verb) **2** [Term for when noun becomes a verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325789/term-for-when-noun-becomes-a-verb?lq=1) **3** [Is it acceptable to use “google” as a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/is-it-acceptable-to-use-google-as-a-verb)

Comment: [List of generic and **genericized trademarks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks#List_of_protected_trademarks_frequently_used_as_generic_terms) the expression in bold is the same answer as in the older question.

Comment: Often, it is misuse of a trade mark.